# Why does adding a new node to front of linked list NOT work in my code?

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

why can't I insert a new node to my linked list as follows? My insertNodeToHead only works if my return type is a Node itself and if I return root. But I want to be able to change the linked list itself without returning anything. Currently, it should print 0,1,2,3,4, but just prints 1,2,3,4.

Here is my code:

```
// Create a singly linked list class
public class Node {
    int data;
    Node next = null;

    public Node (int age) {
        data = age;
    }

    // insert a node to the head of a linked list
    public void insertNodeToHead (Node n) {
        Node root = this;
        n.next = root;
        root = n;
        return;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node root = new Node(1);
        root.next = new Node(2);
        root.next.next = new Node(3);
        root.next.next.next = new Node(4);

        // insert new node
        Node insertNew = new Node(0);
        root.insertNodeToHead(insertNew);

        Node current = root;
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.println(current.data); 
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what your `insertNodeToHead` method does, _specifically_?

Comment: Say my linked list is 1->2->3->4. Now if I want to add new node (0) to this list, my new list should be 0->1->2->3->4

Comment: I'm not asking what it should do, I'm asking what it does do. Walk us through it.

Comment: Oh, sorry. So, first it creates a variable "root" for the current instance of the node. Then the new node "n" to be added points to the root, and then "n" becomes the root itself. However, the instance doesn't change. I can't do "this = root" because java gives me error saying that the left side of the assignment must be a variable itself". I want to change the instance itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `this` means this node: `Node root = new Node(1);` What you want is to set `this = n` in `insertNodeToHead` method, but if using `void` method, you are not able to make `this` points to another node. Ravi Thapliyal's answer has explained this.

One solution is Ravi Thapliyal's suggestion which use another class to hold a reference to the root node. If you do not want to introduce a new class, suggest use a method which return `Node` type to achieve your requirement:

```
public class Node {
    int data;
    Node next = null;

    public Node (int age) {
        data = age;
    }

    // insert a node to the head of a linked list and return the head
    public Node insertNodeToHead(Node n) {
        n.next = this;
        return n;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node root = new Node(1);
        root.next = new Node(2);
        root.next.next = new Node(3);
        root.next.next.next = new Node(4);

        // insert new node
        Node insertNew = new Node(0);
        Node current = root.insertNodeToHead(insertNew);

        while (current != null) {
            System.out.println(current.data); 
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, all your `insertNodeToHead()` method is doing is to attach the current `root` node as the `next` node of the `insertNew` node. Doing `root = n;` has no effect outside of the method since it's just a *local* variable.

Now, technically the new node has become the root of the list but you can't see it because you're still iterating the list from the old `root` node i.e. from the second node of the list which now has `0` at the head.

You need to introduce another class, say `SinglyLinkedList` or something, that holds a reference to the root node and manipulates the list for you. You shouldn't be adding this logic to your `Node` class itself.